# Python-Scapy OSError: [Errno 9] Bad file descriptor when sending a packet

Tags: python, send, scapy

I am a student and part of my current assignment is to write a Python script to generate DDoS attack traffic. I am very new to Python and scapy but we have been supplied with an example script.

```
>>> import logging
>>> logging.getLogger("scapy.runtime").setLevel(logging.ERROR)
>>> from scapy.all import *
>>> packet = IP(src = "192.168.0.3", dst="192.168.0.1")/ICMP()/"HI!!!"
>>> send(packet)
```

However when I send the packet I get this error.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "<pyshell#4>", line 1, in <module>
send(packet)
File "C:\Users\Quentin\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\site-    packages\scapy\sendrecv.py", line 255, in send
__gen_send(conf.L3socket(*args, **kargs), x, inter=inter, loop=loop,    count=count,verbose=verbose, realtime=realtime)
File "C:\Users\Quentin\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\scapy\sendrecv.py", line 241, in __gen_send
os.write(1,b".")
OSError: [Errno 9] Bad file descriptor
```

Comment: Students learn how to DDoS? Interesting approach :)

Comment: It is a network security unit.

This is the example script we were given.

from scapy.all import *

packet = IP(dst="127.0.0.1")/ICMP()/"HI!!!"


send(packet)

packet.show()

Comment: Does it work if you remove the `logging` code and only keep the `scapy` code?

Comment: i have the same problem when running from python idle. From cmd it's working